# Keyboard and Mouse sharing between computers

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse

I used to use [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) for Keyboard and Mouse sharing between computers. Recently I have less luck using it on Windows 7 and with the fact that my desktop has a dual display (Monitor + TV).

Is there a modern solution, that works well with Windows 7, that is aware of multiple screen combinations and that has similar features as Synergy?

Comment: Sorry that I don't have an answer, but the tool is looking nice, thanks ^^

Comment: Fixed the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with [InputDirector](http://www.inputdirector.com/). I've been using it for quite some time now and it's great.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like Synergy has moved to a new domain from the link you posted...  It doesn't say specifically about Win7 but does mention that with Vista and above, issues with screen switching can be alleviated by downloading the 1.4 beta and install as a service.

Comment: +1. Id recommend fixing synergy rather than ripping it out and starting with something new.

Comment: I liked my synergy setup in the past, only got rid of it due to a dual monitor card purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your use case is, but I've found that I like just having my second computer run headless, and connecting to it remotely.  I use NX for persistent X sessions.  Something RDP would work on Windows.

I switched to this setup from Synergy.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running Windows :P

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this exact problem myself! I have a dual monitor Windows 7 desktop (one 37" tv and one 20" monitor) and a Windows 7 laptop. I wanted to share the desktop's keyboard and mouse with the laptop. I tried using Synergy, but it did not work at all. Then, I tried Input Director (www.inputdirector.com) and it worked great.

One thing that I would recommend is to uninstall Synergy before trying to use Input Director. I did not do this, and as a result my keyboard and mouse were experiencing major problems, even on the master computer.

On a side note, if you are using a Microsoft Touch Mouse, the normal scrolling functions will work on whichever computer the cursor is present on, but two-finger and three-finger touch motions will be always be followed by the master computer even if the cursor is present on the slave desktop.